# Iterable as a return type - Iterable itself or a subclass?

Tags: java, iterable

I'm having trouble understanding getAvailableRooms method. I have methods that I need to fill out, but I don't really understand Iterabl getAvailableRooms method.

```
public interface BookingManager {

public boolean isRoomAvailable(Integer room, LocalDate date);

public void addBooking(String guest, Integer room, LocalDate date);

public Iterabl<Integer> getAvailableRooms(LocalDate date);
}
```

How can Iterable be a return type and how is it used? Is it suppose to return a Iterable object or any of subclasses such as List?

Comment: You need to return *something* that is an `Iterable<Integer>`.

Answer (score 1):

It is an interface. It can return any class that implements that interface and you can use the response using the interface-provided methods (you'd have to cast it to get other class-provided methods). Look up Polymorphism for more info.

```
public class BookingManagerImpl implements BookingManager {
 // other methods
  @Override
  public Iterable<Integer> getAvailableRooms(LocalDate date) {
    List<Integer> rooms = new ArrayList<>();
    // add rooms as needed
    return rooms;
  }
}
```